# How can I find out why delayed_job is failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Delayed_job is failing silently. The only message in the log is:

```
2011-05-09T00:06:03-0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:me.local pid:13603)] Starting job worker
```

and that's it. Nothing else.

Interestingly enough, running it in the foreground with:

```
rake jobs:work
```

works just fine. Does anyone know what I can do to figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having difficulty passing the environment.

Apparently -e does nothing now.

```
./script/delayed_job start RAILS_ENV=staging
```

did not work. Still runs in dev mode.

This worked:

```
RAILS_ENV=staging ./script/delayed_job start
```

worked just fine.